# Deleting Video from Wistia using Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl, video, wistia

I am working on Wistia wireframe for Video hosting. I did upload video using Curl PHP. But when I try to delete the particular video using *hased_id* [received from wistia, while uploading video], I am not receiving any response from Wistia and the video is not deleted in Wistia. Can anyone resolve my problem. Here is my code.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $video_id=$_POST['video_id'];
    $api_password ='0f61*********************************************5';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias/".$video_id.".json?api_password=.$api_password.");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

}
    ?>
<form name="upload-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
 <h1>Video </h2>
 <input type="hidden" value="sfcnyx1ra8" name="video_id">
 <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show?  Also, try removing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` from the request as it is not a POST.

Comment: @drew010. thanks for ur suggestion. It works fine.